# Will graduate programs go back to GRE after COVID?

Tags: gre, covid-19

With the pandemic going on, most schools have either decided to make both GRE and its subject tests optional. In all likelihood, would there be a big chance that this is the finishing hammer for the GRE, and make a lot of institutions move away from it?

Comment: Probably won't make a comeback anytime soon. It predicts graduate GPA and degree competition about as effectively as a well-trained RNG.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11812/the-gre-why-does-this-still-exist

Comment: This is an operationally relevant question!!! ... even if non-trivial to answer. And, indeed, the questions with obvious answers are hardly worth asking? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My U.S. grad program in math had already been reducing attention to GRE subject test for years, due to its *manifest* uselessness for predicting success in our grad program. (I've been involved in grad admissions here almost continuously since about 1985, and have been Dir of Grad Studies in math for two stints, so I've really paid a lot of attention to this.)

Until the pandemic, we did tell our own undergrads to take the subject test GRE, since many places still did expect it. In fact, faux-ironically, until recently, we did tend to wonder why someone would *not* have taken the subject test GRE if they had any idea what they were doing... in terms of preparation for or application to grad school in math in the U.S.

A number of other good programs had already, in recent years, downplayed the significance of the GRE subject test score for their applications, so we ourselves had come to "wonder less" why someone might not have taken it.

With the pandemic, and the at-least-temporary vanishing of the GRE subject test, we have more-unabashedly stated that we don't care about a subject test GRE (nor any other part of the GRE).

I would speculate that other math grad admissions in the U.S. have also figured out how to not pretend that the subject test score is a good predictor of success... all the more that it (documentably, both anecdotally and other) never was, and the last year or so has necessitated making decisions without it.

Comment: You have convinced me to retract my vote for "opinion based."  Thanks!

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, :)... there is an unsurprising inertia in these things... but/and in happy cases there does come a tipping point.

Comment: At the program I went to, the subject test GRE wasn't required. I have heard professors at other universities say that they don't care about GRE scores because they think that students cheat. But if it is so clear that it is useless, why is it so prevalent in the first place? Is it because "everyone else is doing it"?

Answer (score 1):

This will vary by institution in the US. Some will return, others not. It is likely to depend on how the experience of making predictions about success of applicants turns out without it. If the other indicators prove adequate there will be little pressure to return.

But, I suspect that many, if not most, will return to using it since, for the institution, it give some information at little cost or effort.

Hard to predict the future, of course.

Comment: Please do not post answers that contain no information.

Comment: This is a good answer: despite the fact that the GRE is not a good predictor of graduate student success, there are a lot of people who are used to using it as a cut off, and the key point from Buffy's answer is that "it gives some information at little cost or effort."

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, please don't try to manage me. I don't answer to your whims. Sorry.

Comment: Another factor to consider: the GRE tests (especially subject tests, but also the general one) have increasingly been criticized from a diversity perspective- here's an example from physics (https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/PT.3.4626). I suspect that this pressure will only continue after the pandemic, and unless departments can really make an affirmative case for keeping it that the path of least resistance will become to move away, at least for the time being.

Comment: Irrespective of their use in admissions, I actually found taking the GRE and the math subject test to be valuable. Humbling, though.

Comment: @JHare That "key point" does not relate to the premise of the question, which is that programs stopped using the GRE due to the pandemic.

Comment: It's just a request.  I do not expect to manage anyone.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, it is, however, insulting. Not the first instance.

Comment: One can reasonably disagree, but in my opinion, posting unhelpful answers is slightly rude.  Requesting that you stop is not rude.  You have posted many good answers, which I upvoted, and your answer quality has improved over time.